# Turning an object into a datetime raising errors

Tags: python, pandas

a two part question

I'm attempting to transform a column into a datetime, an easy task I assume ? as I've done it before on different df's using the documentation without much issue.

```
  df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['24 October 2018', '23 April 2018', '18 January 2018']})
    print(df)
    date
0   24 October 2018
1   23 April 2018
2   18 January 2018
```

I was going through the datetime docs and I thought this piece of code would convert this column (which is an object) into a datetime

```
df.date =  pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%d-%m-%Y",errors='ignore')
```

which gives the error :

```
ValueError: time data '24 April 2018' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y' (match)
```

I've attempted playing with formulas and going through documentation to no avail!

Comment: In order for the error to be raised, you need to omit the `errors='ignore'` part.

Comment: yes that's correct I initially put it in to inspect my DF to see if an outlier was throwing off my DF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong format. `'24 October 2018'` uses `format="%d %B %Y"`. The format specifiers are listed [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

edit: -Demo-

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['24 October 2018', '23 April 2018', '18 January 2018']})
>>> df.date = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%d %B %Y")
>>> 
>>> df
        date
0 2018-10-24
1 2018-04-23
2 2018-01-18
>>>
>>> df['date'][0]
Timestamp('2018-10-24 00:00:00')
>>> df['date'][0].month
10
```

edit 2: second question

```
>>> df['status'] = ['complete', 'complete', 'requested']
>>> df
        date     status
0 2018-10-24   complete
1 2018-04-23   complete
2 2018-01-18  requested
>>>
>>> df[df['status'] != 'complete']
        date     status
2 2018-01-18  requested
```

Comment: `time data datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 25, 0, 0) does not match format '%d %B %Y' (match)` threw this error. When changing the format to y B d i got `ValueError: unconverted data remains: 18`

Comment: @Datanovice I don't know what you are doing wrong, but `df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['24 October 2018', '23 April 2018', '18 January 2018']}); df.date =  pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%d %B %Y")` definitely works.

Comment: thanks! you are right it works in the demo but not on my DF which is exactly the same datetime so I'm not really sure what the issue is. will try above solution.

Comment: Thanks Timgeb, this didn't work for me per se, but it is the correct solution. Thanks I hope this is of help to others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.to_datetime` or the `datetime` library

```
import datetime as dt
df['date'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x,'%d %B %Y'))
```